# Java Hangman code, char array

Tags: java, arrays, char

If any of you can point out the issue in this code, i'll be glad :)
This is just the method im having issue with..

```
public static char[] checkMethod(char[] checkArray, char letter)
{
    boolean flag = false;

    for(int i=0; i<checkArray.length; i++)
    {

        if(checkArray[i] == letter)
        {
            checkArray[i] = letter;
            flag = true;
        }
    }

    if(flag == true)
        System.out.println("Good job!");
    else 
        System.out.println("Aww.. Try again");

    return checkArray;
}
```

Currently the checkArray contains " - - - - -" for the length of the word. This method is supposed to replace the _ with the letter, if entered correctly. 'letter' is the input given from keyboard.

Right now i'm not getting the expected output, instead i'm getting blanks. It seems the checkArray[i] = letter part doesn't work. How do i make it work ?

Any help will be much appreciated 
(i hope i have worded the question correctly.. )

Comment: If checkArray contains "-----" how would you test if the letter is in the word?

Comment: OMG O_O !! My logic was flawed. I need the original array. Thanks!

Comment: If `checkArray[i]` contains `"-----"`, the only time `if(checkArray[i] == letter)` will return `true` is when `letter` is equals to `-` and therefore `checkArray` will remain as it originally was

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you need an additional argument (holding the word) to your function.

Say String word

```
if(word.charAt(i) == letter)
{
    checkArray[i] = letter;
    flag = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have 2 arrays: 1 with the blanks to fill in, and one with the actual word being checked against. Currently you are checking against the blank array, which will never == the letter.

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing checkArray[i] == letter and if true replacing checkArray[i] by letter, but they are already equal. You need to pass the word that you are checking.

```
public static char[] checkMethod(char[] checkArray, char[] wordArray, char letter)
{
   boolean flag = false;

   for(int i=0; i<checkArray.length; i++)
   {

      if(wordArray[i] == letter)
      {
          checkArray[i] = letter;
          flag = true;
      }
   }

   if(flag == true)
       System.out.println("Good job!");
   else 
       System.out.println("Aww.. Try again");

   return checkArray;
}
```